# Smooth manifold with(out) boundary

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I am confused about the definition of smooth manifolds with boundary.

In a book, it says

"We say that $M$ is
a differentiable manifold with boundary if $M$ is a second countable Hausdorff space
which is covered by charts mapping open subsets of $M$ either to open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ or
to open subsets of $H^n$"

If I understand it correctly, then any smooth manifold is a smooth manifold with boundary (because the requirement "to open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is always fulfilled), but it's possible, that the boundary is empty in some cases.
But as far as I see, that's not possible, since it says that $\partial M$ is a $n-1$ dim. smooth manifold and thats not true for the empty set.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The open interval $(0,1)$ is a smooth manifold with empty boundary.

Comment: You could just accept the empty set as a (trivial) $(n-1)$-dimensional submanifold, and everything works.

Comment: So do I understand it right, that any smooth manifold is a manifold with (maybe trivial i.e. empty set) boundary?